# Correct usage of MPI Probe

Tags: c++, mpi

I need to transmit a vector of variable length between processors. more specifically, one processor listens to sends of a couple of other processors. This is what I though would be sufficient:

```
// receiving processor (rank 0):
MPI::Status status;
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Probe(MPI::ANY_SOURCE, my_tag, status);
const auto sender = status.Get_source();
const auto n_bytes = status.Get_count(MPI::BYTE);
std::cerr << n_bytes << std::endl;
auto row = std::vector<size_t>(n_bytes / sizeof(size_t));
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&row.front(), n_bytes, MPI::BYTE, sender, my_tag);

// sending processor:
const size_t n = 10; // example value
auto row = std::vector<size_t>(n, 0);
const auto n_bytes = n * sizeof(size_t);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&row.front(), n_bytes, MPI::BYTE, 0, my_tag);
```

However, the receiving processor reports `n_bytes == 0`. Is the use of `Probe / Recv` correct?

Comment: just trying to see what the problem is, try moving the declaration of `n_bytes` out of the if `rank =0` side, and into the global address space

Comment: @pyCthon what would be the motivation of that? Just to let you know: "Yes, the usage is correct" is a perfectly valid answer, the problem might be elsewhere in my code

Comment: And indeed, that was the case. I'll let anyone know of my mistake by answering to this question.

Comment: Please mark your self-answer as accepted to let people know that this question has been answered.

Comment: @nhahtdh Will be possible in 2 days. Since I can't until then, I added the bold line.. (Actually I will be on vacation, so the bold line needs to suffice for a bit longer)

Comment: @stefan: Oh, well, enjoy your vacation. (Anyway, please remove it later).

Comment: @nhahtdh Of couse I will ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown in the question isn't wrong at all. However the production code differed in one key aspect (which I stupidly thought would be irrelevant to the question).

The error was in the following code (sender remains the same):

```
// receiving processor (rank 0):
MPI::Status status;
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Probe(MPI::ANY_SOURCE, my_tag, status);
const auto sender = status.Get_source();
const auto n_bytes = status.Get_count(MPI::BYTE);
if ( n_bytes == 0 )
{
   std::cerr << "nothing transmitted\n";
   return; // BAD
}
auto row = std::vector<size_t>(n_bytes / sizeof(size_t));
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&row.front(), n_bytes, MPI::BYTE, sender, my_tag);
```

The mistake was to return from the method after probing *without* receiving. Even an empty transmission must be consumed. Otherwise the next call to probe get's the status of the exact same transmission.

It is fixable by calling `MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(NULL, 0, MPI::BYTE, sender, my_tag);` before returning.